# shared_ptr : std::get_deleter does not work

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a very weird beahviour happening when trying to get the deleter of a shared pointer. Here is the problematic bit of code:

```
shared_ptr<IDeckLinkVideoFrame> videoFrame = deckLinkDevice_->GetVideoFrame(decklinkFourCC_);
if(std::get_deleter<ComObjectDeleter<IDeckLinkVideoFrame>>(videoFrame))
{
    // never gets here
}
```

I never get inside the *if* because *get_deleter()* returns *NULL*. Inside the function *GetVideoFrame()* I create the *shared_ptr* with a deleter as follow:

```
shared_ptr<IDeckLinkVideoFrame> DeckLinkDevice::GetVideoFrame(FourCC frameFourCC)
{
BMDPixelFormat pixelFormat = FourCCToBMDPixelFormat(frameFourCC);
shared_ptr<IDeckLinkVideoFrame> frame;
IDeckLinkMutableVideoFrame* videoFrame = NULL;
long rowBytes = 0;
BMDFrameFlags flags = 0;
switch (pixelFormat)
{
case bmdFormat8BitBGRA:
    rowBytes = outputMode_->width_ * 4;
    flags = bmdFrameFlagFlipVertical;
    break;
case bmdFormat8BitYUV:
    rowBytes = outputMode_->width_ * 2;
    flags = bmdFrameFlagDefault;
    break;
default:
    break;
}
if (rowBytes == 0)
{
    MODULE_ERRORF("Pixel format %1 is not supprted") << pixelFormat;
}
else if (CreateVideoFrame(outputMode_->width_, outputMode_->height_, rowBytes, pixelFormat, flags, &videoFrame) != S_OK)
{
    MODULE_ERRORF("Failed to obtain a frame from the output.");
}
else
{
    frame.reset(videoFrame, ComObjectDeleter<IDeckLinkVideoFrame>());
}

if(std::get_deleter<ComObjectDeleter<IDeckLinkVideoFrame>>(frame))
{
    // here it works I can get the deleter
}
return frame;
```

And if I try to call to *get_deleter()* inside this function it works. So it looks like the deleter gets lost when the function *GetVideoFrame()* returns... Any idea what's happenning and how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: show the complete code of `GetVideoFrame()`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].